# std::unique_ptr to transfer ownership of a const object

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, unique-ptr, ownership

I have an object of class `A` created inside a method. This method also creates an instance of an object `B` that takes as constructor argument the object `A` just created. `B` has to take the ownership of the object `A` but it can't modify it. This means that `A` should be deleted when `B` is deleted, but during the lifetime of `B` it cannot modify `A`.

In this case a `std::unique_ptr<const A>` as a member variable of `B` is the right way to transfer the ownership of `A` (using `std::move` in the constructor of `B`) and guarantee that it won't be modified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's precisely the semantics you're looking for. `std::unique_ptr<T>` states "I own the `T` object." A pointer (raw or smart) to `const A` states "I cannot modify the `A` to which I point." Taken together, it's exactly what you're after.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a word about `const A*a->~A();`